# How can I get a cookie that came in a response from a different domain?

Tags: ajax, http, cookies

I'm sending an AJAX request to another domain, and it's sending me a response with a cookie, but document.cookie is empty. How can I make it visible? What permissions do I need? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're attempting can't be done. (It's a browser security issue)

can only be solved by getting the user's browser to submit requests to each domain which will then set its own cookie.

Comment: I don't understand. How does the domain set the cookie? If the browser ignores it, nothing is saved.